PadRight with length of 4 gives very long result
var value = "0".PadRight('4', '0');
    
Console.WriteLine(value);

The result of this is 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in both my project and .NET Fiddle.
Can someone explain why?

Did you mean to write "0".PadRight(4, '0') instead? 4 should be passed as an int, not the char '4'.

The ascii value of the char '4' is 52.

Well this is embarrassing. I have no clue how I managed to put the char there (didn't even know that was possible).

The first parameter of String.PadRight is an int, not a char:

public string PadRight (int totalWidth, char paddingChar);

In this line:
var value = "0".PadRight('4', '0');

'4' is converted to an int using its ascii value which is 52.
The result is 52 zeroes.

gotta love implicit conversions... the source of many bugs.
